# Flutter unit test border radius of container

Tags: flutter, unit-testing

I'd like to know how to unit test the border radius of a container.

I've a box decoration like this:

```dart
  BoxDecoration getBoxDecoration(ChatThemeData theme) {
    return BoxDecoration(
      color: isSender
          ? theme.colorScheme.myBubble
          : theme.colorScheme.otherBubble,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(8),
        topLeft: tail && !isSender ? Radius.zero : Radius.circular(8),
        bottomRight: const Radius.circular(8),
        topRight: tail && isSender ? Radius.zero : Radius.circular(8),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and would like to unit test that the border radius is in fact 0 and on the correct side. However I cannot find that property.

```
testWidgets('Should have tail on the correct side when necessary', (tester) async {
  final msgSender = getMsg('hey', MessageTypes.TEXT, isSender: true);
  final msgOther = getMsg('hey', MessageTypes.TEXT, isSender: true);
  // no tail sender
  await tester.pumpWidget(
    getWidget(msgSender, onSelected: () {}, tail: false),
  );
  var ctnrFound = find.byKey(Key('bubble'));
  var ctnr = tester.widget<Container>(ctnrFound);
  // expect(ctnr., )
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```dart
final decoration = ctnr.decoration as BoxDecoration;
final borderRadius = decoration.borderRadius as BorderRadius;
expect(borderRadius.bottomLeft, Radius.circular(8));
expect(borderRadius.topLeft, Radius.zero);
expect(borderRadius.bottomRight, Radius.circular(8));
expect(borderRadius.topRight, Radius.zero);
```